# Serving client-side DNode library - "cannot find module dnode/web"

Tags: node.js, dnode

I'm trying to build a simple bidirectional DNode app using the DNode tutorial [here](http://substack.net/posts/85e1bd/DNode-Asynchronous-Remote-Method-Invocation-for-Node-js-and-the-Browser).  However I'm not sure how to serve the client-side dnode js.

The example includes the following code:

```
var js = require('dnode/web').source();

var httpServer = http.createServer(function (req,res) {
    if (req.url == '/dnode.js') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type' : 'text/javascript' });
        res.end(js);
    }
//...
```

But the app won't run.  I get: "Error: Cannot find module 'dnode/web'"

DNode is installed via npm.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dnode/web is the really ancient way of hosting the source. Now /dnode.js is available by default so you can just `<script src="/dnode.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same thing, that article appears to be out of date. Go to [dnode's page on Github](https://github.com/substack/dnode) and try the examples there instead. They work.